# get a count on a text search mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a full text search index set up in mongo 2.4 on the jobs collection. I can get full text search results using something like this:

```
db.jobs.runCommand("text", { search: "Australia" })
```

Is there a way to get a count on this similar to `db.jobs.count()`? How about a limit?

Comment: I don't know Mongo very well, but you probably want to chain [`.count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/) (or [collection `.count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)) onto the end of your snippet

Comment: Hi Bojangles, Unfortunately this doesn't work. I wish it was that simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a certain field in the output:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/#text.stats.nfound

Which will give you a figure of:

> The nfound field returns the total number number of documents that match. This number may be greater than the size of the results array, i.e. n, if the result set exceeds the BSON Document Size.

#### Example

```
print(db.jobs.runCommand("text", { search: "Australia" }).stats.nfound);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like if using limit, nfound gives the results returned and "nscanned" the total results. db.jobs.runCommand("text", {search: "Australia", limit: 4 }).stats.nfound. Now to find out how to use skip!

Comment: @user1781563 That is interesting, I would take that up with 10gen on mongodb-user cos semantically I would say that items nscanned do not need to be added to the result as viable matches, though I doubt you will get a difference between the 2 most likely

Comment: @Sammaye What's the answer for Mongodb 2.6?

Comment: @Harry I would say it is the same, there has been no serious changes on that front from what I know