# Mongodb 2.6 - How to know the count of text search results?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I already saw this question and it's outdated. How does this apply to mongodb 2.6 with new $text operator?

Can we get the count? I want to know the solution, performance etc.

[get a count on a text search mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394047/get-a-count-on-a-text-search-mongodb/17394157#17394157)

Answer (score 2):

In `mongodb v2.6` you can make use of the [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/) operator in the aggregation pipeline.

```
var term = "searchTerm"

var result = db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"$text":{$search:term}}},
{$group:{"_id":null,"count":{$sum:1}}}
]).map(function(i){return {"count":i.count};});
```

`result[0].count` will give you the count of documents that have matched.

If you simply want the count, then you could do using the `count()` function.

```
db.collection.count({$text:{$search:term}});
```

You can read [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) more about how to use it with various query operators and how it fares.

Comment: I have tens of millions of records and this count operation is very slow. Any solution?

Comment: @Harry - What about the aggregation? I have edited the aggregate pipeline. Please check how it performs.

Comment: It's still loading after 5 mins, so I quit. My text index is around 11GB. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @Harry Your text index size seems to be very large. Do you have data set up in shards?

Comment: No, I set up on a single machine.

Comment: @Fury did you find any solution?  I have same issue.  Count operations are very slow on  large index